# Hibernate: How to read entity every time from DB, but never update to DB?

Tags: hibernate

In my Spring-MVC (along with Hibernate) project, I have a table called 'Division' containing all divisions in the institute. It is referenced in other table called 'Assignment'. Here is what I want to achieve?
1. Fetch division data always from database using Hibernate. But never update division data while saving 'Assignments' or any other entity.

I am not using any cache. @Immutable reads data only once from database, but, I want to fetch 'Division' data from database every time I access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right you have something like:

```
@Entity
public class Division {
   ...
   @OneToMany
   Set<Assignment> getAssignments(){}
   ...
}

@Entity
public class Assignment{
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   Division getDivision(){}
   ...
}
```

If that is the case; then you just need a FetchType.EAGER:

```
@Entity
public class Assignment{
   ...
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   Division getDivision(){}
   ...
}
```

Comment: I am not talking about EAGER vs LAZY here. I want Division entity to be read only (but should not be flushed or committed to database). My hibernate session should know that this entity is read only, so it won't track any changes and won't commit it to database. But it should always fetch from database. So, when I save Assignment, it should not flush/save Division to database.

Comment: Hi Ketan, it seems to me that  Query.setReadOnly(true)  is the solution for you. Did you take a look at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/readonly.html  ??
Let me know if helps. Cheers...

Comment: I can set Session.setDefaultReadOnly( true ). So, I don't have to set on query, right? Do you have preference ?

Comment: @Ketan Yes, you can. However, all entities manipulated by that session are going to be read only by default. If you need only some entities to be read only; then you can use: Session.setReadOnly(division, true);

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "column_name", referencedColumnName = "reference",
insertable =  false, updatable = false)
private aaa bbb;
```

Notice the insertable and updatable parameters.